# Jquery dialog new button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

As the screenshot suggests, can I add a new button next to close button on top of dialog, I have no idea if this can be implemented or there is any limitation[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `create` event to add your button. This is a simple way to make sure button doesn't get added more than once

```
var newBtn = '<a href="#" class="myDialogBtn"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span></a>';

$('#dialog').dialog({
    title: 'Test Dialog',
    create: function() {
        $(this).prev('.ui-dialog-titlebar').find('.ui-dialog-title').after(newBtn)
    }
})
```

Inspec the existing button in browser console to copy additional css needed

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/eh4Aj/

API Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-create

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, add the given below code to open function of Jquery Ui Dialog

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").append("<input type=\"button\" id=\"yourID\" value=\"My Custom\">");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the jquery ui dialog by inserting a button with jquery `before` function,

**JQuery Code:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#trigger').click(function(){
      $("#dialog").dialog();
      $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").before('<input name="newBtn" id="newBtn" type="button" style="float:right;" value="BUTTON"/>');
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

**Html Code:**

```
<input name="trigger" id="trigger" type="text" />
<div id="dialog" style="display:none">
    <div>
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```